# Using sets as properties that are initialized with the class

Tags: c++, set

I have been trying to use sets as properties for a class.  These sets need to be initialized when the class is initialized.  I have been trying to use pre-initialized arrays and then set the values of the sets to the contents of the arrays.  My problem with this, however, is that it seems like you can only set the contents of a set to the contents of an array when the set is declared which I can't do if it's a class property.  I would rather not individually add each piece of the set.  Any recommendations?  Here's some sample code: 
Creature.cpp:

```
        Creature :: Creature()
{
    Skill Init[] = {Balance,EscapeArtist,Hide,MoveSilently,OpenLock,Ride,SleightOfHand,Tumble,UseRope};
    //DexSkills = ??? (contents of init)
    Skill Init[] = {Climb,Jump,Swim};
    //StrSkills = ???
    Skill Init[] = {Concentration};
    //ConSkills = ???
    Skill Init[] = {Appraise,Craft,DecipherScript,DisableDevice,Forgery,Knowledge,Psicraft,Search,Spellcraft};
    //IntSkills = ???
    Skill Init[] = {Autohypnosis,ControlShape,Heal,Listen,Profession,SenseMotive,Spot,Survival};
    //WisSkills  = ???
    Skill Init[] = {Bluff,Diplomacy,Disguise,GatherInformation,HandleAnimal,Intimidate,Perform,UseMagicDevice,UsePsionicDevice};
    //ChaSkills = ???
}
```

and in Creature.h:

```
#pragma once
#define roll20 (rand()%20) + 1
#define Mod(stat) ((stat-10)/2)
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include "Global.h"


class Creature
{
protected:
std::set<Skill> DexSkills;
std::set<Skill> StrSkills;
std::set<Skill> ConSkills;
std::set<Skill> IntSkills;
std::set<Skill> WisSkills;
std::set<Skill> ChaSkills;
//static const Skill StrSkills[3];
//static const Skill ConSkills[1];
//static const Skill IntSkills[9];
//static const Skill WisSkills[8];
//static const Skill ChaSkills[9];
const int maxHP;
int HP;
int hitDie;
int speed;
int babBase;
int fortBase;
int refBase; 
int willBase;
int AC;
int STR;
int CON;
int DEX;
int INT;
int WIS;
int CHA;
DamageResist DR;
std::vector<Feat> Feats;
Alignment alignment;
//std::set<DamageType> Weaknesses;
//std::set<DamageType> Resistances;
std::set<DamageType> Immunities;
int Resistances [15];
int SkillRanks[40];

public:
//Creature();
int Damage(int damage, DamageType type);
void getDamaged(int damage);
int StatRoll(int stat);
//int StrRoll();
//int ConRoll();
//int DexRoll();
//int IntRoll();
//int WisRoll();
//int ChaRoll();
int SkillCheck(Skill skill);
```

};

and in my global.h:

```
typedef enum {
Appraise,Autohypnosis,Balance,Bluff,Climb,Concentration,ControlShape,Craft,DecipherScript,Diplomacy,DisableDevice,Disguise,EscapeArtist,Forgery,
GatherInformation,HandleAnimal,Heal,Hide,Intimidate,Jump,Knowledge,Listen,MoveSilently,OpenLock,Perform,Profession,Psicraft,Ride,Search,SenseMotive,
SleightOfHand,SpeakLanguage,Spellcraft,Spot,Survival,Swim,Tumble,UseMagicDevice,UsePsionicDevice,UseRope
} Skill;
```

Comment: what is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: Your question is slightly unclear. Do you simply want to initialise some sets in a constructor? Or are the sets intended to be static class members or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple way to copy a C array into a set, you can try something like this:

```
#include <iterator>

...

int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

std::set<int> s;
std::copy(a, a + n, std::inserter(s, s.end()));
```